# Fastest way to connect computer to router?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, nas

I will soon move my router with my NAS to my computer upstairs so I can have fastest speed to my NAS. The thing is, there is a computer downstairs where my router is currently is. that pc will not transfer file to the NAS as often as the one upstairs but is used daily and will sometime send file to the nas. So what is my best option to connect the pc to the router. Also, it is a old pc and doesnt have a wifi card built in. I also saw something called Powerline and was wondering if it would be a good option.

Comment: You have a few options. Powerline is one of them. Another option is to pull a wire. But I suggest You to buy a Wi-Fi adapter. It would be the cheapest and easiest solution.

Comment: I want the fastest solution, not the easiest(well I cannot really run a wire from the router)

Comment: Than powerline is the best solution for You. You can achieve up to ~500 Mbps speed with it. Read: http://www.pcworld.com/article/231419/dlink_powerline_speed_test.html  
It sais that the theoretical speed of the wireless N is 600 Mbps "However, due to environmental barriers, most Wireless-N networks don’t move data faster than 300 Mbps"

Comment: OK, i will try Powerline. What is a good brand?

Comment: I can not answer that, since that is an opinion based question. Try to google your question. I usually enter a site, filter my search for the product I am looking for, read the specs of the products, and if I find the one that suits my needs, I read some reviews about it on forums; and the buyers comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest solution is to use a network cable. But that might be inconvenient, depending on how many walls you would have to go through, etc. You can also use power line networking, by plugging network adapters into your power outlets by the router and the computer downstairs. This can be a slow or unstable solution however. Lastly you can install a PCI wireless card in the computer down stairs, to get wlan support on it.

Comment: I can't run a cable. If Powerline is faster then wifi, then I will go with that. Also, my house wiring is new.